# British royal succession algorithm

Tags: algorithms

I was reading about the rules for royal succession of the British monarchy and thought the easiest way I could understand it is with code (or pseudo-code).  I came up with this (in a C# like pseudo-code):

```
EventHandler CurrentMonarch_Died {
    CurrentMonarch = SuccessorRootedAt(Person.Electress_Sophia_Of_Hanover);
}

enum Gender { Male, Female };  // Male must come before Female

Person SuccessorRootedAt(Person person) {
    if (person.IsAlive && IsQualified(person.Religion, person.Citizenship))
        return person;

    sortedChildren = person.Children.OrderBy(p => p.Gender).ThenBy(p => p.DateOfBirth);

    foreach (child in sortedChildren) {
        successor = SuccessorRootedAt(child);
        if (successor != null)
            return successor;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Is it correct?

Comment: As an aside, you may find [Comprehensive Rules for Game of Thrones Lines of Succession](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/37862/comprehensive-rules-for-game-of-thrones-lines-of-succession) on Sci-Fi.SE interesting.  It has some pseudo-code in it too.

Comment: I don't have enough rep to leave this as a comment, so it will have to be an answer. The current rules of succession no longer have male children taking precedence over females (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Succession_to_the_Crown_Act_2013#Gender)).

Comment: They changed the law before the birth of the new baby, so firstborn now takes precedence, regardless of gender.

Comment: @razethestray: This change is not yet effective, because not all of the Commonwealth realms have implemented it.

Comment: @SimonCB765: See above; Wikipedia on the [Perth Agreement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perth_Agreement) has the full story.

Comment: @razethestray: There's no reason you couldn't add a condition that checks for the date before deciding if there should be ordering by gender.

Comment: I don't think citizenship matters. However, spouse's religion does.

Answer (score 3):

Close, but if you analyse history, it's more like:

```
Person SuccessorRootedAt(Person person) {
  if(!rand%100) //Reality simulator
  {
    if (person.IsAlive && IsQualified(person.Religion, person.Citizenship))
      return person;

    sortedChildren = person.Children.OrderBy(p => p.Gender).ThenOrderBy(p => p.DateOfBirth);

    foreach (child in sortedChildren) {
      successor = SuccessorRootedAt(child);
      if (successor != null)
        return successor;
  }
  else
  {
    return rand();
  }
}
```

And yes, it occasionally causes a whole mess of trouble.

Comment: So does rand() represent invaders, rebellion, forged claims, political maneuvering, incompetent heirs, or yes?

Comment: @PaulMarshall: I think incompentent heirs would *not* be included by `rand()` because `IsQualified()` does not take `Person.Competence`.

Comment: @Philip: If I recall correctly from CGPGrey, `return rand();` should be replaced with `return SuccessorRootedAt(person.getKinglyParent())`.  This is a bit of an oversimplification.  I think it would probably be better to say that if no successor is found, re-run the successor algorithm that was used for choosing the previous king (in this iteration, the previous king will be ineligible).  Of course, this kind of rule is more applicable in the last few hundred years; before that it was more about army size.  And yes, this is applied recursively.  CGPGrey's explanation is probably more accurate.